# Is the id_rsa.pub file needed on client side?

Tags: ssh

If we would use:

1) password authentication through ssh
2) key auth - the public key's line are already in the servers authorized_keys

**Q: So in either these two ways, storing the public key is unneeded on the client side?**

p.s.: I tried to rename the id_rsa.pub file, and I still could log in to a server. so afaik storing the pubkey on client side is not needed. I'm asking this to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want it if you need to add your key to another server (its perfectly normal to have one private key per user per machine, and copy the public key to a lot of machines' authorized keys file).

Its also a very tiny file which doesn't need to be kept secret, so there really isn't any reason to delete it.

If you have deleted it, you can recover it with `ssh-keygen -y`, so its also fairly safe to delete.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding client's public key to server's `authorized_keys` then the client should keep the `id_rsa.pub` just in case.  Beyond that it is not necessary.

Generally that file doesn't take that much space to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Every guide I've read on SSH says you need it, but you should be able to run without it. You'll need to log in every time without it, though. I can't see why you wouldn't have room for it though, it's tiny.